# Add/Delete Rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

so I have an excel table with 2 columns: Times and Count, and 3 Rows: 1:00, 2:00 and 3:00 pm. I want functionality where when the user changes the count value for any of the rows, the count value minus 1 row should be added underneath. So for example for 1:00 pm below, when the user enters '4', it should add three rows below that row for a total of 4 rows. If the user changes the count to '2' it should remove 2 rows so that there are 2 total rows. This is what I have so far:

```
Times              Count    
1:00pm               4         
2:00pm               0  
3:00pm               0
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("C5:C100")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        'Save Workbook before so that original document will be saved
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Dim List As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Dim x As Long
        Dim ExCnt As Variant
        Dim aVal As Integer

        'Find how many rows contain data
         List = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = List To 2 Step -1
            'Store exception value into variable
            ExCnt = Range("C" & i).Value

            With Range("C" & i)
                'Insert rows unless text says Exception Count
                If .Value > 1 And .Value <> "Exception Count" Then
                    .EntireRow.Copy
                    Application.EnableEvents = False

                    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Resize(.Value - 1).Insert
                End If

CleanExit:
            End With
        Next i

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This code adds the right amount of rows for each row but if the user changes the count value, the effect will compound for the existing rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you appreciate how intricate this can actually be.  :-)

Try this solution ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim strKey As String, lngCount As Long, lngOffset As Long
    Dim i As Long, rngNewRows As Range, lngTopRow As Long, lngBottomRow As Long
    Dim bInBetween As Boolean

    ' Anymore than 10 cells and we'll skip this process.
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        On Error Resume Next

        Err.Clear

        lngCount = Target.Value

        On Error GoTo 0

        If Err.Description = "" Then
            If lngCount = 0 Then lngCount = 1

            If lngCount > 0 Then
                ' Get the time value.
                strKey = Target.Offset(0, -1).Text

                bInBetween = False

                ' Check to make sure that the user isn't entering a value in between an already exploded set of rows.
                If Target.Row > 1 Then
                    If Target.Offset(-1, -1).Text = strKey Then bInBetween = True
                End If

                If Not bInBetween Then
                    lngOffset = 0

                    ' Now check each column below and delete or add rows depending on the count.
                    Do While True
                        lngOffset = lngOffset + 1
                        If Target.Offset(lngOffset, -1).Text <> strKey Then Exit Do
                    Loop

                    Application.EnableEvents = False

                    If lngOffset < lngCount Then
                        ' We need to add rows.
                        Set rngNewRows = Target.Worksheet.Rows(Target.Offset(lngOffset, 0).Row & ":" & Target.Offset(lngOffset, 0).Offset(lngCount - lngOffset - 1, 0).Row)

                        lngTopRow = rngNewRows.Cells(1, 1).Row
                        lngBottomRow = rngNewRows.Cells(rngNewRows.Rows.Count, 1).Row

                        rngNewRows.Insert

                        For i = lngTopRow To lngBottomRow
                            Target.Worksheet.Cells(i, Target.Column - 1) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
                        Next
                    Else
                        If lngOffset <> lngCount Then
                            ' We're over the count, determine the rows to delete.
                            Target.Worksheet.Rows(Target.Offset(lngCount, 0).Row & ":" & Target.Offset(lngOffset - 1, 0).Row).Delete
                        Else
                            ' We have 1 row and that's all that's been asked for.
                        End If
                    End If

                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

... you clearly have some other rules that need to be applied but this should get you going.  Check out the image below to see it in action.

A few points ...

- It tries to cater for individuals entering values in column B within the exploded range and if they do that, it won't react to the value.  Not sure if that's a requirement but I assumed it was.
- 0 will be treated as 1, so both 1, 0 and cleared will result in the resetting of the line.
- Deletions happen at the bottom.  So if the number goes from 10 to 3, it will delete the last set of rows to bring it back to 3.
- It will only react to 1 cell at a time being changed.  It reduced the complexity of the solution.

Outside of that, you're on your own.  :-)

[image]